# Always active bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a horizontal dropdown menu in bootstrap. It works on **hover (not per click)** and the menu item who is/was actually hovered stay active.

Everything work just fine expect one think - when user click anywhere outside of menu the drop down menu disappear (which is normal state for bootstrap menu).

Is there any way to disable **disappearing of dropdown menu**?

Here you can test and see the menu : **[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Pu3P6c2nlO)**

Comment: suspicious? In what way? On bbotply

Comment: my apologies. never heard of that site before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Just cancel the hiding action* :

**JS**:

```
$('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
    return false;
});
```

**Bootply** :  http://www.bootply.com/qUgRfmICyQ